# Selenium: ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable when trying to access autoComplete text box

Tags: java, selenium

I am stuck with the `WebElement` which I am trying to access on the Webpage with the below code but still getting mentioned error. The Element allows to autocomplete the subjects and multiple subjects to be entered in the single text box.

```
WebElement Subjects = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='subjectsContainer']"));
        
        
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Subjects);
        

        String subject1 = prop.getProperty("subject1");

        String subject2 = prop.getProperty("subject2");
        
        String subject3 = prop.getProperty("subject3");

        Subjects.sendKeys(subject1);

        Subjects.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        Subjects.sendKeys(subject2);

        Subjects.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        Subjects.sendKeys(subject3);

        Subjects.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

[WebElement accepts the multiple subjects to be entered by user which autocompletes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3TcP.png)

[Selenium WebElement error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYBh8.png)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page you are working on?

Comment: https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form

Comment: On what code line are you getting this error?

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add some delay or element visibility validation before you trying to send text to this element.
Additionally it's not recommended to use `JavaScript` click instead of `WebDriver` click unless you have no choice.

Comment: Sure. You have first to wait until the page and the element you are going to use are completely loaded.

Comment: Thanks, Now it is working partially after adding Explicit wait when clicking the element
```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Subjects)).click();
```
but at the time of execution the sendKeys is not working as getting error as ""main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable"

Comment: Sure. You need to add delay before sending texts too, not just before clicking. If this is another element.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below answer for my query as it is now working fine after putting Explict wait condition and locating correct webElement with tagname  'input'.

```
//Load the data from the Properties file
         String subject1 = prop.getProperty("subject1");
          
        String subject2 = prop.getProperty("subject2");
          
        String subject3 = prop.getProperty("subject3");


        //WebElement to capture the visibility condition
        
        WebElement Subjects =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='subjectsContainer']"));

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Subjects)).click();        
          
        WebElement Sub1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='subjectsInput']"));

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='subjectsInput']")));

        Sub1.sendKeys(subject1); //Send first Subject

        Sub1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='subjectsInput']")));

        System.out.println("ENtered subject 1" + subject1);

        Sub1.sendKeys(subject2); //Send second subject

        Sub1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        System.out.println("ENtered subject 2" + subject2);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='subjectsInput']")));

        Sub1.sendKeys(subject3); //Send thrid subject

        Sub1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        System.out.println("ENtered subject 3" + subject3);
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution to many not interactable errors is simply this:

```
Thread.sleep(500);
```

I find this tactic to be extremely useful in quickly debugging problematic elements before implementing a more performant and elegant wait solution like you mentioned in your update.